# How/When to use a Cython Extension Type vs a Cython Struct to store data that is passed around class functions

Tags: python, c++, cython, cythonize

I am interested in creating a data structure to hold data/information that is passed around to different functions. The way we currently do it is the following code:

```
# right now we use a C-struct to hold data that is passed
# around in a separate class 'A'
cdef struct Record:
    double threshold       
    double improvement     

cdef class A:

   cpdef py_dostuff(self):
         cdef Record record
         
         record.threshold = new_threshold
         record.improvement = new_improvement
         
         cy_dostuff(&record)
   cdef void cy_dostuff(self, Record record) nogil:
         do_some_computation(record.threshold, record.improvement)
```

This uses a C-style struct which unfortunately doesn’t support inheritance so if we wanted to subclass “A” with another class “B” that uses a “subclass” of the struct, it does not work. My attempt at using a class does not work. Ideally, I would be able to do something like the following without sacrificing performance. My thinking is that it should be possible to replace the struct with a purely Cython extension type because I'm only using C-level stuff, but the extension type would enable me to subclass `Record` and `A`.

```
# now, I would like to use a Cython extension type to hold data that is passed
# around in a separate class 'A'
cdef class Record:
    cdef double threshold       
    cdef double improvement     

cdef class A:

   cpdef py_dostuff(self):
         cdef Record record
         
         record.threshold = new_threshold
         record.improvement = new_improvement
         
         cy_dostuff(&record)

   cdef void cy_dostuff(self, Record record) nogil:
         do_some_computation(record.threshold, record.improvement)

# The reason I would like to use a Cython extension type is that it can then support clean inheritance of the data structure
cdef class NewRecord(Record):
    cdef double threshold       
    cdef double improvement     
    cdef int new_attribute

# E.g. a new subclass of 'A' would still work even if all we did was extend the logic to a "NewRecord"
cdef class B(A):
    cpdef py_dostuff(self):
         cdef NewRecord record
         
         record.threshold = new_threshold
         record.improvement = new_improvement
         record.new_attribute = new_attribute

         cy_dostuff(&record)

     cdef void cy_dostuff(self, Record record) nogil:
         do_some_computation(record.threshold, record.improvement, record.new_attribute)
```

My questions are:

1. How can I substitute a pure-Cython class (with no Python objects to allow nogil operations) in place of the struct correctly?
2. Would there be performance differences?
3. If I cannot, why not and what are workarounds to passing struct like data structures around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I substitute a pure-Cython class (with no Python objects to allow nogil operations) in place of the struct correctly?

There's nothing particularly tricky about using a Cython `cdef class` in place of the struct - you can pass them to `nogil` functions and access their non-`object` `cdef` attributes without requiring the GIL:

```
cdef class A:
    cdef double threshold
    cdef double improvement

    def example_func(self):
        with nogil:
            self.threshold = do_something(self)

cdef double do_something(A a) nogil:
    return a.threshold
```

Please consider whether you actually need to work without the GIL (i.e. you're doing multi-threading). A lot of people thing "nogil==fast" and ask for nogil solutions for largely cargo-cult reasons.

Note that you cannot take an address of a `cdef class`. `cy_dostuff(&record)` would become `cy_dostuff(record)` in your (non-working) example.

> Would there be performance differences?

Probably not much. A `cdef class` is essentially a struct. Internally by pointer (rather than by value) and allocated on the heap so that might make a small difference. Cython takes care of the details for you though.

> If I cannot, why not and what are workarounds to passing struct like data structures around?

You can do "inheritance by composition":

```
cdef struct Record:
    double threshold       
    double improvement

cdef struct NewRecord:
    Record base
    int new_attribute
```

The C standard makes it explicitly allowed to cast between `Record` and `NewRecord` pointers to support this exact use. So if you have a function that takes a `Record` pointer you can do `f(<Record*>&my_new_record)`

Comment: The issue I have though is that if I have a 'cdef nogil' function inside a 'cdef class', and try to initialize a variable to store object 'Record' and initialize it. I get "local variable 'record' referenced before assignment.

Comment: You mean the line: `cdef Record record`? You need to do `cdef Record record = Record()`. However this will require the GIL

Comment: Ah I see. Then there's no way to sub a struct with an extension type if the struct is instantiated within a set of nogil functions? 

Some context: In scikit-learn, we use a struct to pass around data. However, relying on a struct is challenging to subclass. Using the pointer casting method also runs into the issue of managing memory because we need to malloc memory to hold the pointer for different possible "Records" (i.e. `malloc(size_of_record(NewRecord))`).

Comment: You you cannot instantiate a Python object within a nogil block. And an extension type is just a Python object. You're basically limited to passing it into functions and accessing attributes. I'll take your word that records can't be stack-allocated

Comment: I see. So we just have to figure out a way to first instantiate the Cython extension type within a non-nogil block and then we can use it within nogil functions. This is a related question, but is it easy to cast between two extension types? E.g. cast from `Record` to `NewRecord` and vice-versa.

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/25118#discussion_r1043068944